# How to send array of data with blade templates and Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to send below section's data as an array to Laravel backend. Is there method to accomplish that without stringifying?

[image]

```php
// preferred output

$members = [
    ["name" => "Sam", "location" => "US"  ],
    ["name" => "Mike", "location" => "UK" ]
  ];
```

Comment: use `<select name="members[0]['name']">` and `<input name="members[0]['location']">` and so on... `index` in `members[index]['name']` and members[index]['location']  would be dynamic and increased by 1

Comment: @KavanPrajapati This answer helped me. but I had to drop ' s in every name attribute. ex:   <select name="members[0][name]">,   thanks for your answer

Comment: No my bad, don't use single quote or double, just simply write `members[0][name]` , I've answered the question, see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your html form like below,

```
<select name="members[0][name]">

<input type="text" name="members[0][location]">
```

and so on...

index in `members[index][name]` would be dynamic and increased by 1

And in your `controller` function you will get `members` array like,

```
dd($request->members);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form with select and location on each row.

- First **loop and push all values in one array**
- Then use **JSON.stringfy()** to convert the data in **JSON format**.

Here is the example snippet:-

```js
var data = [];
document.querySelector("#submitForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
    
   document.querySelectorAll(".member_name").forEach((member,index) => {
      let name = member.value;
      let location = member.nextElementSibling.value;
      data.push({name: name, location: location});
   });

   // Convert data into JSON format
   data = JSON.stringify(data);
   console.log(data);
      
   // Send Data to backend
});
```

```html
<form action="submit" method="post" id="submitForm">
  <div>
    <select name="member_name" class="member_name">
      <option value="member1" selected>Member 1</option>
      <option value="member2">Member 2</option>
      <option value="member3">Member 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="member_location" class="member_location">
      <option value="location1" selected>Location 1</option>
      <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      <option value="location3">Location 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="member_name" class="member_name">
      <option value="member1">Member 1</option>
      <option value="member2">Member 2</option>
      <option value="member3">Member 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="member_location" class="member_location">
      <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
      <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      <option value="location3">Location 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="member_name" class="member_name">
      <option value="member1">Member 1</option>
      <option value="member2">Member 2</option>
      <option value="member3">Member 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="member_location" class="member_location">
      <option value="location1">Location 1</option>
      <option value="location2">Location 2</option>
      <option value="location3">Location 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can adjust the html for errors and other stuff with or without blade syntax as you wish.

Comment: This is a perfect alternative, but I was looking for a solution without  javascript, Thanks for your time

Comment: @Mani No worries. If you find this answer helpful, then vote up so the future visitor can understand that the answer is helpful. Thanks